# Magento 2.2: How to remove add_to_wishlist button from, and add SKU view in, recently viewed products widget in module

Tags: magento2.2, blocks, custom-template, recently-viewed

I want a extra tab on product page with 4 previously viewed products. Besides that I want to remove "add_to_cart,add_to_compare,add_to_wishlist" buttons and add SKU attribute to recently viewed products in my module.

Probably not the right approach, but I do get 4 recently viewed Products. I have this code now:

> Knot\PreviousTab\registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
'Knot_PreviousTabPDP',
__DIR__
);
```

> Knot\PreviousTabPDP\etc\module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Knot_PreviousTabPDP" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

> Knot/PreviousTabPDP/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
        <block class="Knot\PreviousTabPDP\Block\PreviousProductsTab" name="previous_products.tab" as="previous_products_tab" template="Knot_PreviousTabPDP::previous_products.phtml" group="detailed_info">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Previous Products</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

> Knot/PreviousTabPDP/view/frontend/templates/previous_products.phtml

```
<?php 
echo $this->getLayout()
->createBlock("Magento\Reports\Block\Product\Widget\Viewed")
->setDisplayType("recently.view.products")
->setPageSize("4")
->setTemplate("widget/viewed/content/viewed_grid.phtml")->toHtml()
; ?>
```

and a empty

> Knot/PreviousTabPDP/Block/PreviousProductsTab.php

```
<?php

namespace Knot\PreviousTabPDP\Block;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;

class PreviousProductsTab extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your approach, first you need to copy the template file to your current theme and make the needed customization.

Copy the file located in vendor/magento/module-reports/view/frontend/templates/widget/viewed/content/viewed_grid.phtml

To
app/design/frontend/ThemeVendor/YourThemeName/Magento_Reports/templates/widget/viewed/content/viewed_grid.phtml

Now around line 26 make the below changes

`$showWishlist = false;
 $showCompare = false;
 $showCart = false;`

To add the Sku around line 50 add the below code

`SKU:- escapeHtml($_item->getSku()) ?>`

Final output will look as shown in the screenshot
https://prnt.sc/lbo12b

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a way  to do this with module only, keep it separated from Themes?

Comment: @Bart Of course it is possible, instead of copying the template file to theme directory you can place it in your module's view directory. Change your previous_products.phtml file with the below content  <code>echo $this->getLayout()
->createBlock("Magento\Reports\Block\Product\Widget\Viewed")
->setDisplayType("recently.view.products")
->setPageSize("4")
->setTemplate("Knot_PreviousTabPDP::widget/viewed/content/viewed_grid.phtml")->toHtml();
</code>